# Does zero change in magnetic flux always imply zero emf induced?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

If you have a uniform B field, with a finite piece of wire inside it. Assuming the B field spans all space and the wire cannot leave the field. Are you able to create an emf by moving the wire ?

I say there is only one possible way, and that is if you rotate it so from its starting perpendicular to the field position it does parallel to the field. That would create a change in flux.

But are you able to create emf if the wire stays perpendicular to the wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wire is flexible, you could change its bounded area $A$, thus changing the magnetic flux.

I'm imagining a "closed" loop where the two ends of the wire meet up. In your case of  case of a uniform field that's perpendicular to plane of the wire, $\Phi_B=\pm BA$, depending on your choice for the direction of the corresponding area vector. Then, if you change $A$ by changing the shape of the wire, $\Phi_B$ would change.

Comment: Alright, it was a question on an exam I wrote a few days ago. It was multiple choice so bending the wire was not an option.
It was actually asking which of the options would create the biggest voltage when comparing the two ends of the wire. The B field was going into the page. And my choices were, move the wire , up or down, left or right, in and out of the page, or zero induced current

Answer (score 0):

To get the biggest effect, make the direction of the field, the wire, and the motion of the wire be mutually orthogonal.  The effect is that the magnetic field can produce a force with a component along the direction of the wire (which is different than the direction of the velocity of the charges), and the person pulling the wire can do work on the conduction charges.  The protons and non conduction electrons will stress the wire and it will strain to make it longer than usual, but the conduction electrons will have work done on them, just like a battery does work on conduction electrons.